# Run java program using cmd

Tags: java

I cannot run my java using cmd

[image]

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: `java -cp build Subset` maybe?

Comment: Do you see `Subset.class` in the directory?

Comment: he'll probably have to compile all the files, so `javac *`?

Comment: do you have a static void main entry point declared in your class?

Comment: @soynerdito - that would cause a different exception.

Comment: @soynerdito: judging by the `exception` that the OP points out, I don't think having/not having a `static void main entry point` would make a difference :)

Comment: Make sure that Subset is on the ritgh path and check class has the main() and before executing the class file, compile the java file using javac ,if any jars to preferred at run time pass with -cp and go forth for executing the class file

Comment: What is your question?  Even if the question is obvious to you, it pays to add it for the benefit of those trying to *answer* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've to compile it before you try `java Subset`. [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) on creation, compilation and execution of Java source files in command prompt might be of help to you. As a quick update, here's what you can consider doing:

- Compiling your code using `javac`
- Once compilation is successful, executing using `java` command

Comment: To the down-voter: Can you please explain the reason behind down-voting this? I would love to update/edit the answer based on your comment, but please, when you `down-vote `, an explanation would be useful!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Subset` class in the classpath. Netbeans places the compiled classes in the `build` directory, so try (as I stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256559/run-java-program-using-cmd/12256584#comment16431669_12256559))...

```
java -cp build Subset
```

Make sure you've built via Netbeans. If you haven't, you can also do...

```
javac -d build src/Subset.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **compiling the Subset.java**.. For this you will need to go to the directory where your `Subset.java` is located using Command Prompt, then execute the below commands.

**Eg:**

`javac Subset.java`

then,

`java Subset`

Answer (score 0):

Just cheking, But in the IMG says that the file is in Queue/src, But you're trying to Run it from Queue.. Hay you tried to change the path?